# Replace non-printable characters with " (Inch sign) VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I need to replace non-printable characters with `"` (Inch sign).
I tried to use excel `clean function` and other UDF functions, but it just remove and not replace.
**Note**: non-printable characters are highlighted in blue on the above photo and it's position is random on the cells.
this is a sample string file [Link](https://easyupload.io/tkfd1w)`
The expected correct output should be **12"x14" LPG . OUTLET OCT-SEP@ process**
In advance grateful for useful comments and answer.

Comment: Have you considered substitute()?

Comment: Please, try `ActiveCell.Replace Chr(25) & Chr(25), """"` In order to understand what characters to be replaced, you should iterate between the string letters and return `Debug.Print Mid(x, i, 1), Asc(Mid(x, i, 1))`, where `x` is the letter and the second one the ASCII number. Then, replace it with `""""`...

Comment: @FaneDuru ,works correctly. actually I did my best before post this issue and all fixes was about remove and not replace

Comment: Do you have something against `Replace` method? I am not sure I can get you...

Comment: @Fanedure , as an expert on array , could you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71793443/check-if-new-values-of-target-as-array-equal-to-old-values-of-target-as-arra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you can try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(25)&CHAR(25),CHAR(34))
```

Or the VBA pseudo-code:

```
[A1] = [A1].Replace(Chr(25) & Chr(25), Chr(34))
```

Where `[A1]` is the obvious placeholder for the range-object you would want to use with proper and absolute referencing.

---

With ms365 newest functions, we could also use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(34),,TEXTSPLIT(A1,CHAR(25)))
```

Comment: Please, How could you identified the unprintable character as (CHAR 25) ?

Comment: @Waleed I tried explaining that in my comment, 23 hours ago...

Comment: @FaneDure ,now It is clear & understood for me.great thanks 

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expressions within a UDF to create a flexible method to replace "bad" characters, when you don't know exactly what they are.

In the UDF below, I show two pattern options, but others are possible.

- One is to replace all characters with a character code >127
- the second is to replace all characters with a charcter code >255

```
Option Explicit
Function ReplaceBadChars(str As String, replWith As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
    
Set RE = CreateObject("Vbscript.Regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "[\u0080-\uFFFF]" 'to replace all characters with code >127 or
    '.Pattern = "[\u0100-\uFFFF]" 'to replace all characters with code >255
    .Global = True
    ReplaceBadChars = .Replace(str, replWith)
End With
End Function
```

On the worksheet you can use, for example:

```
=ReplaceBadChars(A1,"""")
```

Or you could use it in a macro if you wanted to process a column of data without adding an extra column.

***Note:** I am uncertain as to whether there might be an efficiency difference using a smaller negated character class (eg: `[^\x00-\x79]` instead of the character class I showed in the code. But if, as written, execution seems slow, I'd try this change)*

Comment: I tried ,but bad characters still as it, ( tried also with both Pattern)

Comment: @Waleed something else going on? Please copy paste a representative string so that it can be copied and used for testing.

Comment: I already added a link for test workbook on my question

Comment: @Waleed Without the data, I did not realize that the code you wanted to remove was in the lower part of the regular ASCII range.  Given that knowledge, it's just a matter of changing `pattern`.  For example, if you wanted to exclude all codes below 32 and above 255, you could use:  `.Pattern = "[^\u0020-\u00FF]+"`  (*the codes are the HEX representation of the character codes*).  If you just have the one character to replace, regex is over kill and other solutions offered are better.  But if you need to replace a bunch of characters, then this is a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
Cells.Replace What:="[The caracter to replace]", Replacement:=""""
```

Comment: `""` is an empty string. As far as I've been able to determine, it doesn't match a non-printable character.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my post
Just copy the special caracter and past it in the VBA code

Comment: I can not copy the special character and past it in the VBA code